# Geometric representations of affine Lie algebras

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, research-level

I have recently been reading literature on [geometric constructions of representations of affine Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212401) by Nakajima and others. In particular, the representations arise as cohomologies of moduli spaces of sheaves on a surface.

For a smooth surface, $S$, if we consider the Hilbert scheme of $n$-points $S^{[n]}$, for a suitably chosen cohomology theory, the vector space formed by,

$$\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty H^*(S^{[n]})$$

is a highest weight representation of the Heisenberg algebra on $H^*(S)$. A [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.04953) has shown if $S$ is an ADE surface, like those studied in the context of gauge theory, one obtains a larger action of an affine Lie algebra of corresponding ADE type.

Since Verma modules appear in conformal field theory, is there also a physical context or motivation for such geometric constructions of representations (including string theory and more broadly gauge theory)?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that within string theory any field theoretical symmetry can be engineered via some brane configuration. This is true for a wide class of finite groups, simply-laced Lie group symmetries, and even affine symmetries. See [Geometric Engineering of Quantum Field Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9609239) for details.

I will summarize two brane configurations that give rise to gauge theories with affine Lie group symmetries and some applications of those constructructions.

1. **Type IIA strings over an $A_{n}$ singularity** are dual to a set of $n$ adjacent $NS$-$5$ branes of the type IIB theory (page 17 of [Branes and Toric Geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9711013) and [Geometric Singularities and Enhanced Gauge Symmetries](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605200)
    for details). Now the point is that an $A_{n}$ singularity can be though locally as a $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ geometry and intuitively you can take the $n \rightarrow \infty$ limit to construct the $A_{\infty}^{\infty}$ quiver. The brane configuration dual to this $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ geometry is an array of adjacent $NS$-$5$ branes following the pattern of the $\tilde{A}_{n}$ affine [Dynkin digram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra#Constructing_the_Dynkin_diagrams). Notice that this related to your actual question because a $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ geometry can be thought as an $A_{n}$ singularity inside a $K3$ surface and the $n \rightarrow \infty$ limit can be taken if this $K3$ is non-compact.

**Applications**

- The reference [Crystal Melting and Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610005) (page 7) use the latter construction to compute the Donaldson-Thomas invariants of a local $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} \times \mathbb{C}$ geometry.
- In the page 15 of [F-theory and the Classification of Little Strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05565)
   an affine $\tilde{A}_{n}$ geometry is explicitly engineered and used to obtain theories with sixteen superchargers in six dimensions.
- You can learn in the page 72 of the famous [Strong Coupling Test of S-duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9408074) about the relationship between the latter construction, the moduli space of instantons on $ALE$ singularities and two dimensional rational conformal field theory.
- An interesting application for the geometric Langlands duality in the context of complex surfaces emerges in [Five-Branes in M-Theory and a Two-Dimensional Geometric Langlands Duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1107)
   by considering the lift of the construction from above to $M$-theory on a Taub-Nut space $TN_{n-1}$ and recalling that $TN_{n}$ is locally  $\mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

2. **$N=2$ quiver gauge theories in $4d$ with affine $ADE$ symmetry:** Here the trick is nearly the same as above. Embbed an array of singularities following an affine $ADE$ pattern into a $K3$ surface or a Calabi-Yau threefold. Deformations with $N=1$ supersymmetry can also be constructed allowing deformations by superpotential terms. Reference: [A Geometric Unification of Dualities](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0110028).